# Multiple jqueryfileupload widget within a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I try to replace classic input file with JqueryFileUpload widget.

Here is my context :

- I can have one or more file input in the same form.
- The form is meant to create server side objects (each input is a field of this object and each file is a "resource" object linked to the main created object). Those object are stored in a database.
- When the final user submit the form, I'd like to :

  - do many validation (for other inputs)
  - if all is ok, then trigger the ajax upload of file(s). A server-side handler create the
    needed ressource object(s).
  - when all the uploads are completed (I can know that by using the widget callbacks), then I submit the main form (the action form is not the widget handler but a page that do the job and display a message) to create the main object : I don't want to send the file(s) here but only the ressource objects id that the handler send me back to link them to the main object).

My  problem is, when I trigger the fileUpload the form is submitted and the action form page is loaded. The handler isn't called.

I made test with a simple page : if the widget is not within a form it works fine :

```
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <input class="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

but if I put it in a form the form is always submitted and I can't prevent this.

```
<body>
    <form action="myPage.aspx">
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <input class="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

My questions are :

- Doesn't the url option override the form action ?
- Can I not use different target for the widget and the form that contains it ?
- Can I put multiple widgets in a single form ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay just for information it was a pretty stupid mistake from my side, I used a  which default behavior is 'submit' so my form was always submitted.